# Which GLSL ES extensions are available on various iOS devices?

Tags: ios, glsl

I'm looking for a list of all extensions available on any iOS devices (and which are available on which device). I haven't found the right page in the apple docs despite a lot of searching, but I'm sure it's there somewhere. Any pointers?

Comment: In addition to the answers already provided, GLBenchmark has lists of supported extensions for each iOS device on their site: http://www.glbenchmark.com/phonedetails.jsp?benchmark=glpro21&D=Apple+iPad+3&testgroup=gl (the link is for the iPad 3 OpenGL ES extensions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should print out all extensions:

```
NSString *extensionString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)];
NSArray *extensions = [extensionString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
for (NSString *oneExtension in extensions)
    NSLog(@"%@", oneExtension);
```

Source: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/12/opengl-es-extensions-on-iphone.html?m=1

Comment: @Tommy Thanks for the edit, I was wondering how that was code I wrote until I looked at the answer date and saw it was three years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Apple maintains a list of GPUs used in its devices and which extensions are supported on each in its [iOS Device Compatibility Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599).

Comment: Old version https://web.archive.org/web/20150224003127/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here are the extensions available on the latest iPad:

```
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_depth24 
GL_OES_element_index_uint 
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap 
GL_OES_mapbuffer 
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil 
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 
GL_OES_standard_derivatives 
GL_OES_texture_float 
GL_OES_texture_half_float 
GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear 
GL_OES_vertex_array_object 
GL_EXT_blend_minmax 
GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float 
GL_EXT_debug_label 
GL_EXT_debug_marker 
GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer 
GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean 
GL_EXT_read_format_bgra 
GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects 
GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod 
GL_EXT_shadow_samplers 
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic 
GL_EXT_texture_rg 
GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample 
GL_APPLE_rgb_422 
GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 
GL_APPLE_texture_max_level 
GL_IMG_read_format 
GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
```

Comment: Note that these may change with iOS versions as Apple adds extensions, so you may need to qualify this with the version you were running when you checked this.