# Rounding error in texture lookup on iPad / OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm using a texture attached to a framebuffer as a custom depth buffer. In a first rendering pass, I render to the texture so it stores the depth values. In the second rendering pass, I do a lookup from this texture to decide whether to render or discard the fragment.

**This works well, except that on the device (iPad 3), there are some annoying artifacts which seem to come from some kind of rounding error** which happens when the depth values are written to the texture. I tried writing some fixed value like `0.5` to the texture, but when it is read back from the texture, it's more than `0.03` higher or lower than `0.5`.

I 'encode' the depth value into three RGB values (the fourth component, alpha or `w`, is ignored):

```
const highp vec4 packFactors = vec4(1.0, 256.0, 256.0 * 256.0, 256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0);
const highp vec4 cutoffMask  = vec4(1.0 / 256.0, 1.0 / 256.0, 1.0 / 256.0, 0.0);

void main() {
    highp float depth = ...
    ...
    highp vec4 packedVal = fract(packFactors * depth);
    packedVal.x = depth;      // undo effect of fract() on x component
    gl_FragColor = packedVal - packedVal.yzww * cutoffMask;
}
```

This way, I get 3x8 bits precision to store the depth (inspired by http://www.rojtberg.net/348/powervr-sgx-530-does-not-support-depth-textures)

In the other fragment shader (second rendering pass), I read from the texture like this:

```
    highp vec4 depthBufferLookup = texture2D(depthTexture, vDepthTex);
    highp float depthFromDepthBuffer = dot(depthBufferLookup, vec4(1.0) / packFactors);
```

using the same values for `packFactors` as in the first shader.

I would expect this procedure to give a decent precision, but an error of more than `0.03` at a value of `0.5` makes it pretty unusable.

**Any hints?**

BTW I'm using the following texture type:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Comment: I think you can just use a depth texture (that page is a little out of date). A quick search of GLES2 extensions on iPad (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159811/which-glsl-es-extensions-are-available-on-various-ios-devices) would suggest GL_OES_depth_texture is available these days.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to do that, but got stuck, see separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598789/rendering-to-depth-texture-unclarities-about-usage-of-gl-oes-depth-texture

Comment: After some more research, I think that `GL_OES_depth_texture` is no option for me, because the fragment shader calculates the depth per fragment, not per vertex. This means that the depth values I need are in `gl_FragColor` and not in the depth values like `gl_FragCoord.z`.